# How to edit line and polygon layers at the same time?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, topology, polygon-creation

I have two layers, lines and polygons. Lines are basically the boundaries of the polygons. Is there any way that when I change or reshape the lines the polygons get updated automatically? 
I normally change the lines first and since they have to match the associated polygons, I convert them back to polygons again. This way, I need to update the attributes of all the polygons or I have to reshape the polygons according to the change I did to the line layer. When I use topology check I am able to catch the issues and correct them using the correcting topology options. Nevertheless, I was wondering if there is a more efficient way/ approach to do it.

Comment: What version and license level of ArcGIS for Desktop are you using? In any event I think you should use the term "shared geometry editing" to look for info about this and you will need to use either map or geodatabase topology.

Comment: I am using ArcGIS 10.0

Comment: Yes, I should have used the term "shared geometry editing" for more clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many [topology tools](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/An_overview_of_topology_in_ArcGIS/006200000001000000/) in ArcGIS but you need at least Standard or advanced licence. As you can use "feature to polygon" and topology check, I assume you do have it.

Therefore you can add the "topology toolbar" ([for 9.3](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Topology_toolbar) or for [10](http://www.esri.com/news/arcwatch/1112/learn-how-to-create-a-map-topology-in-arcgis101.html)). There is a tool called [topology edit tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01mm0000001m000000) that will do what you want.

Comment: Map Topology should also be an option for anyone with a Basic license that does not have access to Geodatabase Topology.